# Polymorphism in Design Pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have observed that most of the design patterns (I refer mostly from the Gang of Four book) are all based on polymorphism. That leads me to a "enlightened" moment that OOP's polymorphism is the most important feature in the paradigm.

Some of the patterns use polymorphism are: strategy, factory, bridge...

With that, I don't understand why we are not just teaching developers really good polymorphic behavior of OOP instead of overloading them with a bunch of patterns which in fact are based on polymorphism?

Comment: Wait, they're being taught patterns? Since when?

Comment: Because there are three (some say four) levels of knowledge: knowing there exists something ("what is polymorphism"), knowing how to use it ("how to make various patterns using polymorphism" - you forgot delegation, btw) and why are you doing it ("why do we use a certain pattern in this *context*"). @Ignacio: Patterns are tought since 1992 / 1995 roughly depending on your university ofc.

Comment: Doug, I agree with you that developers could gain a better understanding of polymorphism.. At the same, however, I don't think developers, as a profession, are synonymous with those expected to have an understanding of high level abstract math.  I've met people (recruiters infact) with CS degrees from fairly prestigious universities that emphasized on applicable and practical knowledge over abstract and conceptual, so (now) my understanding of Computer Scientists doesn't reflect that level of understanding to be self-evident either.

Comment: So, perhaps, it's better to just expect people to be familiar with design patterns in common 'computer languages' and not Type Theory in Mathematics.. By the way, I think it's a good indication of your understanding and ability to reflect on this: for you're able conceptualize and relate the underline concepts being described in those patterns..

Answer (score 1):

Well, polymorphism is one of the fundamental concepts of OOP -- it's at a different level of abstraction than the more detailed patterns.

I don't think there is a problem having names for and teaching the more detailed/dependent patterns, it really does help with communication.  But as you suggest, a solid understanding of polymorphism is definitely required before a developer would be able to effectively implement any of the dependent patterns.

Comment: +1: Yes, basically what Doug is saying is "Oh my god!! Biology is nothing more than chemistry!". He is trying to be a "greedy reductionist". Design-patterns are useful *precisely* because they are polymorphic standards...

Comment: @rsenna .. you've made several good points.. but this last one is not among them... even 4 years after this reflective moment for Doug, these design patterns do not even reference polymorphism as a term in their discussion/introduction, let alone a staple on which the entire pattern relies on. That was the point of contention with OP, as I understand it to be.. It was also my point of interest when I googled 'polymorphism in design patterns', of which the link to this page return in.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't

> really good polymorphic behavior

actually **be** how to apply the Gang of Four patterns in a **good** way?

As in, how to apply strategy as a tool so that you don't violate [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) for example.

Comment: That's my point! When reading GoF book, there is no mention about polymorphism. Instead readers are just presented with the patterns and what they do. If you have really good knowledge about polymorphism you would probably say "oh, just a bunch of sugar-coded wrapper around polymorphism"

Comment: @Doug The patterns are not "wrappers" around polymorphism. You can make the relation because you use them with polymorphism, but the patterns could also be applied using other principles as well (duck-typing, for example)

Comment: @Joseph , I disagree.. I think the reason should be obvious too: the notion behind design patterns is they use a series of concepts: like polymorphism.. the issue the OP raised was that the patterns are being promoted without discussing or promoting those concepts as being the basis of the design.

Comment: @Joseph, additional duck-typing is polymorphism.. it just isn't strong-typed.. but their is an interface being used there.. just not one that is declared.. The issue here is people seem to think polymorphism requires inheritance.. that's not the case.. perhaps if they were instructed on what polymorphism was BEFORE they were introduced to design patterns that use it.. they would know better.

Comment: also, before we get into the chicken and the egg debate in concept terming (chronologically or otherwise).. polymorphism is the term in Mathematical Type Theory.. I consider duck-type is a more expressive term, but it's a facet of - or synonymous to a type of - polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Every language has its features that are the "killer features" of the whole concept. OOP, being some of the largest and oldest branch of advanced languages has polymorphism, but I can point out other amazing features such as strong functional programming, closures, parallel execution, and other unique things to other languages that are along the same lines of amazingly-powerful features that are must-haves.
Teaching just one method quickly turns you into a one-trick-pony. A strong foundation in theory allows you to pick up a very "different" language like Lisp or Erlang and know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a red herring. *Some* languages implement this as polymorphism. Others can implement it as interfaces. Still *others* can use duck-typing. Forcing readers/students into thinking "polymorphism" doesn't actually help in all situations without also being taught the other two mechanisms, which don't exist in every language. At that point it becomes noise.

Comment: Probably we have distinct interpretations of polymorphism. To me, "Polymorphism" happens when the same contract "abstracts" distinct implementations. So I could argue that both duck-typing (in dynamic languages) and interfaces (in static languages) are just distinct implementations of polymorphism...

Answer (score -1):

Because, while polymorphism is *used* to implement the patterns *in OO languages*, but the patterns can be implemented without it (for example, imagine implementing a factory in C).

Additionally, design patterns are, like polymorphism, tools that help developers solve problems. Only learning a subset of the tools (eg, only polymorphism) will put developers at a disadvantage because they will need to “work from first principals“ (so to speak) instead of basing their work (and their thought) on higher level concepts (like design patterns).

Comment: You can't implement the factory design pattern without polymorphism.. it embodies polymorphism completely, it's less of a pattern than it is a construct form of polymorphism..
Additionally, polymorphism is not a tool; the only 'problem' it 'solves' is architectural considerations for productivity: scaling, maintenance.. (thus it's not a solution, it's a consideration).. it doesn't effect functionality what-so-effect, nor does it provide a possibility that would otherwise not exist without it.

Answer (score -1):

@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I don't think duck-typing, interface and abstract class are different interpretation of polymorphism. If a implementation can not be determined at compile time and must be defined at runtime, it is polymorphism. You can name that concept anything you like, at the end of the day it is the definition of polymorphism. This is coined late/dynamic binding albeit the same principle.

Comment: @user129148: 1) I said that, not Ignacio. 2) Still, you are wrong. Please look at wikipedia: "In strongly typed languages, polymorphism usually means that type A somehow derives from type B, or type C implements an interface that represents type B. In weakly typed languages types are implicitly polymorphic". So your definition of polymorphism is actual *only* on static languages.

Comment: The wikipedia article however is not correct. If I have a dynamic language like groovy or smalltalk and two classes A and B, they are only polymorphic if they both implement the same mehthod! If they don't they aren't. It is the exact same situation as in a static typed language. Also keep in mind dynamic languages usually do support inheritance! So the only difference is that static typed languages require inheritance for polymorphism but dynamic ones don't.